# Count numbers with repeating digits in a given range

Tags: algorithm, numbers

How to find the number of numbers with repeating digits (Ex : 11, 101, 15231 : all have repeating 1s) without the use of modulus function. The range is supposed to be user defined. There are some solutions using combinations but that is subjective to a predetermined range. If the range is given as 52 and 156 then how to find the solution in the best possible way.

Comment: For integers x % y is the same as x - x / y * y.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to figure out the number of numbers with repeating digits, its easy to count the number of numbers with unique digits in each position and subtract it from all numbers possible to get the actual result.

```
# of numbers with repeating digits(R) = all possible numbers(A) - # of numbers with unique digits in each position(X)
```

Now, to count the `X` and `A` within certain range[L, R], we can count first from `0` to `R` and subtract `0` to `L - 1`.

```
ans[L, R] = ans[0, R] - ans[0, L - 1]
```

I am not giving code example now. Just putting some food for your thoughts, let me know where you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have  a set S of numbers.

let A be a matrix of dimension ||S|| x 10.

```
int row = 0
for each n in S:
    let exp = log10(n)
    for(int i = exp; i >= 0; i--){
        let division = n / pow(10, exp)
        A[row][ division ] = 1
        n -= division * pow(10, exp)
    }
    row++
}
```

with this pseudo-code you can get all the digits that exist in all your numbers, than you just need to check if all numbers have some common digit:

```
void check(matrix A){
    for(int i = 0; i < A.columns; i++){
        boolean all_equal = true
        for(int j = 0; j < A.rows; j++){
            if(A[i][j] != 1) all_equal = false
        }
        if(all_equal) print("all numbers have " + i + " digit in common")
    }
}
```

hope that helps :)

---

I guess you have considered the possibility of turn the numbers into strings, so this solution does not include strings